AuthFailure while trying to call a method through amazon api
I am trying to create an EC2 instance on AWS in an automatical manner.
I am calling a HTTP method through an amazon endpoint using a HTTP client installed on my computer, which clearly is not on AWS.
I am calling the endpoint in the following way, as specified in amazon documentation:
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=RunInstances&
ImageId=ami-0129bfde49ddb0ed6&
MaxCount=1&
MinCount=1&
KeyName=chiavepem.pem&
SecurityGroupId.1=sg-0983aeb061077d2ab&
Placement.AvailabilityZone=eu-north-1&
AWSSecretKey=<redacted>&
AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>

However, I get this response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Code>AuthFailure</Code>
            <Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
    <RequestID>c3c559d8-fe3f-4e60-bd16-1db621dfcbe4</RequestID>
</Response>

Regarding AuthFailure, Amazon Documentation says:

The provided credentials could not be validated. You might not be
authorized to carry out the request; for example, trying to associate
an Elastic IP address that is not yours, or trying to use an AMI for
which you do not have permissions. Ensure that your account is
authorized to use Amazon EC2, that your credit card details are
correct, and that you are using the correct credentials.

I made sure these conditions are respected.
What might be the cause for this specific behavior?
As a side note, I am using access keys here, but I understood that it is not the best way to authenticate a call to the aws api, but i didn't find any valid alternative for doing so. As far as I understand, I cannot use my IAM credentials to authenticate to the API.
Maybe someone could point me in the right direction on this matter as well.
Thanks.

It is far easier to use the AWS CLI or one of the AWS SDKs to make requests. I think your error is due to the request not being signed.

As a part of an exercise I try to imagine myself calling amazon functionalities externally. I imagine having some scripts on my workstation or on a hybrid cloud server that is outside of AWS. Would AWS CLI or a specific AWS SDK help me achieve that? Wouldn't I need to authenticate either way? I saw some snippets of using a sdk and I think accessing a resource required some degree of authentication.
I am pretty new to AWS and the various workflows. Sorry if my question stands out.

Those requests will need to be authenticated, but the AWS CLI and SDKs handle the signing for you.

#1 There is no way that an aws endpoint can be consumed directly sending the credentials in the url. Share the docs #2 Share how are you consuming the http endpoint

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html
The snippet that I posted is simply a GET request to the amazon endpoint that is inspired by the examples in this doc. See sample Requests down below in the doc.

The authentication to call an aws platform rest endpoint is not easy like oauth2 client-credentials flow, in which we can exchange the credentials for an access_token and the use it to consume the required endpoint (create an ec2 instance in your case)
AWS-Signature is Like oauth1
I tried in the past and the authorization is something like oauth1 in which the request is signed using some values like credentials and others.
This is not easy, that's why aws and similar (gcp, azure, etc) has a sdk in all the well known languages. That sdk do the request sign by you and other complex tasks (expiration, etc)
Anyway if you want to do it manually (+1 for you), the signature process is called  : AWS Signature

Check:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-signing.html
AWS Version 4 signature snippet code with example in javascript
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html

As you will see, it is similar at OAUTH1 in the way that we need to sign the entire request request

Signing http messages
As an extreme summary, using some strings (keys, dates, etc) the clean http message:
POST /foo?param=value&pet=dog HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Date: Tue, 20 Apr 2021 02:07:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Digest: SHA-256=X48E9qOokqqrvdts8nOJRJN3OWDUoyWxBf7kbu9DBPE=
Content-Length: 18

Body:
{"hello": "world"}

To something like
POST /foo?param=Value&Pet=dog HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com
   Date: Tue, 20 Apr 2021 02:07:55 GMT
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Digest: sha-512=:WZDPaVn/7XgHaAy8pmojAkGWoRx2UFChF41A2svX+T\
     aPm+AbwAgBWnrIiYllu7BNNyealdVLvRwEmTHWXvJwew==:
   Content-Length: 18
   Signature-Input: sig1=("@method" "@authority" "@path" \
     "content-digest" "content-length" "content-type")\
     ;created=1618884473;keyid="test-key-rsa-pss"
   Signature: sig1=:HIbjH+xF/g==:

Body:

PHK7a9sRL1IXNaagCNN3ZxJsYapFj+JXbmaI5rtAdSf\
     SvzPuBCh+ARHBmWuNo1UzVVdHXrl8ePL4cccqlazIJdC4QEjrF+Sn4IxBQzTZsL9y\
     9TP5FsZYzHvDqbInkTNigBcE9cKOYNFCn4D/WM7F6TNuZO9EgtzepLWcjTymlHzK7\
     aXq6Am6sfOrpIC49yXjj3ae6HRalVc


To fully understand check

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9421/
https://justinsecurity.medium.com/signing-http-messages-962510d65895
https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/nab/en-us/platform/developer/all/rest/rest-getting-started/restgs-mle-intro/restgs-mle-digest.html
https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-message-signatures-04.html
https://github.com/jbowes/httpsig

Also you can review the code of some library in your favorite language
Try with some client like postman
If you understand that signature is required, I suggest you to use postman, insomnia o soapui to verify that signature exist and your credentials are ok.
Check:

https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/amazon-web-services-aws/request/f4xhx4m/list-instances?tab=auth

Implement the aws-signature
If your credentials are ok and the signature works with postman, you can try to implement manually using your favorite language. Here some samples:

https://community.boomi.com/s/article/How-to-Generate-an-AWS-Signature-Version-4
https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.signature
https://github.com/mhart/aws4

aws sdk instead manually invocation
Check:

How can you create an EC2 Instance from a launch template with the node.js AWS SDK

